# MySQL STRCMP with underscore is not functioning properly

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT STRCMP('_', 'a');
```

Returns 1, while it should have returned -1.

`ASCII code of '_' (underscore) is 95, and ascii code of 'a' is 97`.

In other languages like python and node it returns the right answer.

Any clue what is wrong here?

Why is MySQL treating underscore differently?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

> STRCMP() does a case insensitive comparison, while here I required
>   case sensitive comparison.

```
mysql> STRCMP('_', 'a' COLLATE utf8_bin);
```

Returns the right answer `-1`.